# trailing slash from URL url for some php url only

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to rewrite some URLs with `.php` to trailing slash URLs. However, I don't want to rewrite all URLs.

**My code:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /[^?\s]+\.php
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php?|jpg|gif|png|css|js|html|json|xml|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|zip|csv|xlsx|webp|txt|gz|rar)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

**I want force slash on:**

- /about-us.php => /about-us/
- /services.php => /services/

**I don't need slash on:**

- /cart.php => /cart.php
- /auth.php => /auth.php

Comment: Do you want `/about-us.php` to be `about-us.php/` ?

Comment: @starkeen No is want /about-us/

Comment: So in browser `/about-us.php` should be shown as `/about-us/` but `/cart.php` should be shown as `/cart or should it just remain `/cart.php` ?

Comment: @anubhava code is full,  /about-us.php should be shown as /about-us/ and /cart.php should be /cart.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use these rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(about-us|services)(?:\.php)?[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(php?|jpg|gif|png|css|js|html|json|xml|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|zip|csv|xlsx|webp|txt|gz|rar)$ [NC]
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Make sure to use only these rules in root .htaccess and test from a new browser or command line `curl`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this to remove the trailing slash from your `/cart` and `/auth` URIs .
Put the following two rules right below `RewriteBase` line in your htaccess :

```
#remove the trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(cart|auth)/$ $1 [L,R]
#rewrite /cart and /auth to their original location
RewriteRule ^(cart|auth)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: i have added your code below my code but not worked :(

Comment: its always redirecting to /cart/